# Jump to the next row of a textarea as I don't want the text to reach the end of the text area

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top: 20px">
  <label style=" width: 99%; font-weight:normal; margin-left: -15px" class="surveyquestion">2.b. Identify other lending programs managed by applicant.</label>

  <textarea style="width:90%; " id="otherLendingPrograms" maxlength="8000" data-bind="css: otherLendingProgramsCSS , attr: { title: otherLendingProgramsToolTip }, event: {focusout: checkLostFocus.bind($root, $data, 'otherLendingPrograms')}, value: otherLendingPrograms"></textarea>
</div>
```

I would like the text to be shifted to the next row underneath the first row when it reaches specific amount of digits. I don't want the teach to go all the way to the end of the text area box.  for example: text is `123456789`

I would like `12345` for the first row and `6789` goes to the next one under. Just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather going too much complicated on a simple thing,
You can use CSS to adjust the length of the line.

```
textarea{
    max-width:200px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

This would give a word-warp and line change when the width is 200 px, You can adjust the max-width too.

There is savvy example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap).

Comment: Thanks Amar, but the whole point is I have an Asterisk on the mandatory text fields overlaps the text in some cases. The Asterisk is at the upper right corner of the textarea. I don't want the text to over lap with it.

Comment: If that is the reason , you could use padding inside the text area, this not only solves your problem, rather it makes your text area look more design perspective and feels good. see  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Thanks amar, but the padding is controlling hight and left. I want it to cut only from the right end of the text! Any solution?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @TrEx , you could use " padding-right " property , this won't affect any other sides.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much Amar! It works.

Comment: @AmarPathak please (for the future) rather point to some better documentation resources that w3schools.